# PhoneGap Google maps - map does not display

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I am writing an application that uses PhoneGap and needs to integrate Google Maps in it. I have used this sample from the online documentation provided by Google:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDlFl3vPEbgzrr-1KX5E20z_1DowB2ASus&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works correctly if I open it in my web browser (Chrome, FF, IE...). However, in my emulator (and device as well) it only shows a blank page. Any tips?

Comment: your emulator (and device) version?

Comment: I just copied the code above and sent it through build.phonegap.com and I got a working google map on an Android 2.3.4 device. I would suggest setting the html and body width property to 100%, just as a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually solved this problem. The problem was that I had multiple html pages, and this script was on the second page. Therefore the scripts did not execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem occured since I was using multiple html pages on the same application. Since phonegap will use ajax calls to replace the dom of the index page, it fails to load the scripts on those pages as well.

Two solutions exist here:

1. To use only a single html page
2. To load the second page using

   rel="external"